# Persist object data during page refresh

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

My scenario for MVC4:
I have a contact form with a subsequent survey page.  Each page of the site has a "change language" option, which refreshes the page, passing a querystring parameter back into the same page, changes the CurrentCulture, and pulls text from the appropriate resource file.

When a user submits the contact form, they are taken to the survey page.  I am not sending the contact id into the survey page via querystring for obvious security reasons.  What I'm doing is setting a TempData["ContactId"] object value on contact form submission in the controller method and letting the survey controller method read from that object.

The problem is when the user is on the survey page after submission and then elect to change the language.  This causes the page to refresh, and the TempData object is then null.

Any advice on how to persist the ContactId during a page refresh like this?

Comment: I think that `TempData` is [only persisted through a single request](http://forums.asp.net/post/3692191.aspx), so maybe you could store the language data in a session variable instead.

Comment: Awesome.  If this is all you need and it works for you, I went ahead and posted my comment as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

I think that TempData is only persisted through a single request, so maybe you could store the language data in a session variable instead.

Answer (score 0):

Session and TempData are the same thing.

However, you should use TempData because the object is automatically removed from session memory after it's been accessed once.